# In mockk, can every be called twice on the same method

Tags: android-espresso, mockk

I'm doing a UI test with several steps

In the first step I need to simulate a network down condition when user clicks a button, and check the expected behavior, then I need to simulate the user retrying clicking the button, but this time the network has recovered

The code would look somewhat like this

```
@Test
fun dumbTest() {
    mockkStatic(NetworkUtils::class)

    every (NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable()) returns false
    onView(withId(button_id)).perform(click())
    onView(withId(text_id)).check(matches(withText("no internet)))

    every (NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable()) returns true
    onView(withId(button_id)).perform(click())
    onView(withId(text_id)).check(matches(withText("has internet)))
}
```

The real code is much more complex than this, so I'm not using constructs like `returnsMany`

The question is: does mockk supports calling `every` multiple times on the same method with different results like I did?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this works.
You can simply verify it by putting

```
assertThat("NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable() should be true",NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable())
```

just under the every {} line.

Another way to be 100% sure would be to mock your Static Method first with false,
than call unmockAll() to reset everything and remock it again, now with value set to true.